# recordSetVar - quick question

Tags: visualforce

This is a newb query.

```
<apex:page standardController="Expense__c" recordSetVar="list_exp" >
<apex:pageblock >
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!list_exp}" var="l" >
<apex:column value="{!l.id}"/>
<apex:column value="{!l.Type__c}" />
</apex:pageblockTable>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:page>
```

I understand that the variable "list_exp" will contain all the records of "Expense__c".

1. Does this mean that it is internally firing a similar SOQL like below ?

   SELECT "all_fields" FROM Expense__c
2. In many of the use cases though, we want only a filtered set of records. Then how useful this variable ("recordsetVar") will be in those cases ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zen

Yes, by default recordSetVar includes all the records for the object in your org.

but its not a blunt select all and load everything into that list at once. its more like using querymore to get a bunch of records and then further more when you access the next set based on how you use/present the data.

I suggest you to go this book [Visualforce In Practice](http://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf) - **Chapter 4** which has a lot of details on **Standard Set Controller and recordSetVar** along with how you can implement **pagination, filterting**, mass updates, etc..